# Recursive unsorted array search algorithm in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Let's say we want to write a function in C that finds a specified target value in an unsorted array of ints. In general, this is simple and runs in O(n) time:

```
int search(int *data, int len, int target)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(data[i]==target) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Let's say we're being masochistic and want to approach this with a divide and conquer algorithm instead.  We'll run into trouble on the recursive part because we can't exclude half the array each time, like we can with binary search:

```
int search(int *data, int start, int stop, int target)
{
// Base case: we've divided the array into two size subarray
    if(stop==start+1)
{
    if(data[start]==target) return start;
    if(data[stop]==target) return stop;
    return -1;
}
/* The recursion part is tricky.  
    We *need* to parse both halves of the array, because we can't safely
    exclude any part of the array; it's not sorted, so we can't predict
    which half it's going to be in.*/
else
{
    /** This obviously doesn't work. */
    int mid = (stop-start)/2;
    return search(data, start, mid, target);
    return search(data, mid+1, stop, target);
}
}
```

Is there any way to make this work?

NOTE: This is *not* asking people to do my homework for me, as some of you may think when reading this question.  It is, however, inspired by curiosity after I encountered this problem when trying to solve a question in an assignment that I've submitted earlier this week.

Comment: Read quick sort algo it will help you to solve your problem

Comment: not sure if I understand the question, because it seems so simple `int sts = search(data,start,mid,targte); if (sts == -1) return search(data,mid+1,stop,target); else return sts;`

Comment: Use `int mid=start+1` - the degenerate case of divide-and-conquer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the recursive call to:

```
else
{
    int mid = (stop-start)/2;
    int x = search(data, start, mid, target);
    if (x == -1)
        return search(data, mid+1, stop, target);
    else 
        return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to your question is no, you can't achieve any benefit using the binary split approach if the data is unsorted.

Comment: Specifically, if the data is unsorted, there exists *no* algorithm that will let you find the location of a given element in less than O(n) time.

Comment: @interjay: the question was "Is there any way to make this work?", the answer is "no"

Comment: Actually you can achieve benefit by binary range splitting if your search is multithreaded. How much you gain on a simple 'int' equality search versus the added complexity is another matter. With a more complex search criteria then the OP (for example find a prime among them) it can give you real benefits.

Answer (score 1):

If the data are not sorted you can not use binary search.
But divide and conquer can be used with the following recursive logic (linear search):

```
int search(int *data, int len, int target)
{
    if (len == 0)
        return -1;
    else if (data[0] == target);
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + search(++data, len-1, target);
}
```